# How to filter dictionary depending on value versus list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to create a new dictionary comparing the matching values from the dict1 and list1 and passing the keys from the dict1 and values from the list1 to the new dictionary.

```
dict1 = {'F0': (117, 118),
         'F1': (227, 118), 
         'F2': (337, 118), 
         'F3': (447, 118), 
         'F4': (557, 118)}


list1 = [(117, 118), (447, 228), (227, 448), (557, 558),(557, 118)]

result:
dict2 = {'F0': (117, 118),'F4': (557, 118)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict1 = {'F0': (117, 118),
         'F1': (227, 118), 
         'F2': (337, 118), 
         'F3': (447, 118), 
         'F4': (557, 118)}


list1 = [(117, 118), (447, 228), (227, 448), (557, 558),(557, 118)]
print {k:v for k,v in dict1.items() if v in list1}    #python dict comprehension
```

**Output:**

```
{'F0': (117, 118), 'F4': (557, 118)}
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using a dictionary comprehension.

```
list1_set = set(list1)
res = {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if v in list1_set}
```

`list1` is converted to a set for O(1) lookup within the comprehension. This is possible because the elements of `list1` are tuples and therefore hashable.

Result:

```
{'F0': (117, 118), 'F4': (557, 118)}
```